# points are not visible clearly in nvd3 ghaph

Tags: jquery, graph, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3.js to show a graph with 3 different keys. AMong those 3, 1 has so many co-ordinates and rest of 2 s are only one one co-ordinate. Now these single co-ordinate is not visible properly. My code is like:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart().margin({
        top: 30,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 45
    }).showLegend(true).tooltipContent(function (key, y, e, graph) {
        return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' + '<p>' + e + '% at ' + y + '</p>'
    });

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
    });

    d3.select('#lineChart svg')
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});

data = [{
    "values": [{
        "x": 1025409600000 ,
            "y": 2
    }, {
        "x": 1028088000000 ,
            "y": 4
    }, {
        "x": 1030766400000 ,
            "y": 1
    }, {
        "x": 1033358400000 ,
            "y": 3
    }, {
        "x": 1036040400000  ,
            "y": 0
    }, {
        "x": 1038632400000  ,
            "y": 3
    }],
        "key": "Cool"
},{
"values": [{
        "x": 1025409600000 ,
        "y": 2
           }],
 "key":hot
    }
]
```

Thought the `hot` point is showing if I mouse over the cursor, but it is not visible the position.
Please guide me how to make it visible if the key has only one co-ordinate.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATED with images
[image]
[image]

Comment: could you please your output image

Comment: Please check the updated images.

Answer (score 6):

You need to increase the opacity from 0.

```
.nvd3.nv-line .nvd3.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point {
  fill-opacity: .7;
}
```

And you can increase the size of the circle by using `chart.size(300)`

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/fFqSny?p=preview

Comment: sorry it is increasing the size. But initially I have only one co-ordinate then it is not showing that until unless I mouse over on that particular point. But I want to show the points before mouse over.

Comment: This plunk uses the default size with one data point from the start.   http://plnkr.co/edit/4OnDy0?p=preview
Can you post your css?

Answer (score -1):

You can also use 'fillOpacity'.

e.g. `chart.bars1.fillOpacity(0.7)`

See:

[Hand over fillOpacity for bars in multiBar and multiBarHorizontal charts #1614](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/pull/1614)
and
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/707

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13341091)

Comment: Any constructive criticism how I can improve this answer? There does not seem to be any _"essential parts of the answer"_ for me to include here, so I simply gave an example.